# What can the third section be in -> chaining sequence?

Tags: php, function, class, oop, methods

I've seen two like these:

```
$this->propertyName;
$this->methodName();
```

And I know the code should look like this:

```
class myClass{

    public $propertyName;

    public function methodName(){
       // statements
    }
}
```

Recently I saw a code like this:

```
$this->CI->form_validation->set_message('investigate', '{field} ' . lang('wrong'));
```

What is `CI` *(a method?)*? What's `form_validation`? What's `set_message`? Are these nested methods? How does its code look like?

Comment: *"What is CI (a method?)?"* - Most likely CodeIgniter, if that's what you're asking. You'd need to read the docs.

Comment: They're not methods. Anything without brackets is just a property, and that property is quite likely to be an object in this example, since you can then call properties/methods of that object using another ->. Only the call to set_message is a method call. It's fairly basic PHP syntax, and similar to OO syntax you can find in other languages. In C# it might look like `this.CI.form_validation.setMessage(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method can return an object. You can assign this object to a variable and then call methods on it:

```
$objB = $objA->getObjectB();
$objB->someMethod();
```

Or you can skip the assignment and just inline it;

```
$objA->getObjectB()->someMethod();
```

As long as your methods return objects, you can just keep stacking them up:

```
$objA->getObjectB()->getObjectC()->getObjectD()->getObjectE();
```

The same holds true for object properties. A public property can hold another object:

```
$objA->objB = new objectB();
$objA->objB->someMethodOnObjectB();
```

So methods that return an object and public properties that contain an object can be stacked like this. You can mix them too:

```
$objA->getObjectB()->somePropertyOnObjectB->someMethod();
```

Also see [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). It's common for objects to return instances of themselves for mutator methods. This allows you to turn this:

```
$obj = new Object();
$obj->setFoo('foo');
$obj->setBar('bar');
$obj->setBaz('baz');
$obj->doSomething();
```

Into this:

```
$obj = new Object();
$obj->setFoo('foo')->setBar('bar')->setBaz('baz')->doSomething();
```

And in PHP 5.6+, you don't even have to assign the object to a variable, you can dereference the `new` call directly:

```
(new Object())->setFoo('foo')->setBar('bar')->setBaz('baz')->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

`CI` is a `object`. In this exact context it is a class property, object type. Theoretically you may have also a method/function that return an object. Something like:

```
$ClassInstance->MethodThatReturnAnObject()->ObjectProperty = 'bla';
```

or even

```
$ClassInstance->MethodThatReturnAnObject()->ObjectMethod();
```

And the chain may continue with more levels.